# Blender Snow Simulation

Tags: fluid-simulation, rigid-body-simulation, smoke-simulation, cloth-simulation

How to Create This Snow Simulation.

[image]

Comment: I am not that into blender dynamics, but I think that with current tools being provided by blender itself there is nothing that it may help you for doing so complicated simulations. In that case I would go for Mantaflow build or flip-fluids. 
Typically you need particles with attributes similar to fluids, like viscosity for instance and a way to displace the dynamically.

Comment: It would be done also by different combinations of using tools such as weight painting (dynamically) - in order to displace the snow - and fields (like magnetic) attached on a collider sphere, but these are just few ideas. The most trivial part is to deform the rest of the snow in a more natural way.

Comment: You should check out  https://youtu.be/82zWmOqE0Nc

Comment: You might be interested in checking out the Molecular Script Add-on, as someone has created a near-identical effect to the one you are looking for, with it: https://youtu.be/TJxbiCEoo1Y